# Find out if argument passed to function is an rvalue (@"something") or lvalue (foo) in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Is there a way to find out if the argument passed to a function is an r-value or an l-value in Objective C?
For example,

```
NSString* foo = @"FOO";

[self foobar:@"FOO"];          ...1
[self foobar:foo];             ...2
```

where foobar is a function:

```
-(void)foobar:(NSString*)str{
    //do something
}
```

I need to be able to find out within the function foobar if it was called by (1) or (2). I want to avoid having to change the function signature.

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you could expand on why you need to know this?

Comment: Both calls pass exactly the same argument to the method.

Comment: i am fetching translated text for the passed argument. When passed as @"" i know the argument is an english word whereas when passed as a reference it could be in any language. If there is no way to distinguish I guess i will have to use a common key for all the translations of the same word.

Comment: Just change the function signature to distinguish meaning.

Comment: I want to avoid changing the function signature as that would mean changing the function call everywhere in the project.

Comment: There is no way to tell.  You can infer that it *might* be one or the other based on the subclass of the string, but it's nowhere reliable, given that iOS can substitute one for the other at its whim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Constant and non-constant `NSString` objects do have different types, as demonstrated below, however I'm not sure this is a particularly good method of distinguishing between strings that need translating and those that don't.

You should probably use Apple's own [Internationalization Support](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html), however personally I am going to use the approach documented by (one of) the *Delicious Library* authors, [here](http://blog.wilshipley.com/2009/10/pimp-my-code-part-17-lost-in.html).

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

void foo(NSString *s) {
    NSLog(@"Type of '%@' is %@", s, NSStringFromClass([s class]));
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSString *s1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"A %@ string", @"formatted"];
        NSString *s2 = @"A constant string";
        foo(s1);
        foo(s2);
    }
    return 0;
}

2013-09-17 16:34:05.667 test[9866:707] Type of 'A formatted string' is __NSCFString
2013-09-17 16:34:05.668 test[9866:707] Type of 'A constant string' is __NSCFConstantString
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This totally worked. However, I will look into Apple's Internationalization Support link and see if i can leverage that. Thanks once again.

Comment: @abhineetprasad Found the link I was looking for and updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no distinction because both are the same thing, both pass an object of class NSString.

This:

```
[self foobar:@"FOO"];
```

is exactly the same as doing this:

```
NSString* foo = @"FOO";
[self foobar:foo];
```

The leading @ in `@".."` denotes that this string will be created as NSString*.